# jQuery UI Sortable Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How do I track what position an element is when its position in a sortable list changes?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

You can use the `ui` object provided to the events, specifically you want the [`stop` event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#event-stop), the [`ui.item` property](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) and [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), like this:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }
});
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/HgAQu/), remember the `.index()` value is zero-based, so you may want to +1 for display purposes.

Comment: As an additional note, if you want to track where the moved item came from (move from position 0 to position 2) then you need to access the ui.item.index() value in the start event and store that value.

Comment: Is there a way to find sortable portlets div-id within #sortable div?

Comment: Also, if you need to track position **during drag** with `sort`, you can use `ui.placeholder.index`. Index starts at position 1.

Answer (score 133):

I wasn't quite sure where I would store the start position, so I want to elaborate on David Boikes comment. I found that I could store that variable in the ui.item object itself and retrieve it in the stop function as so:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Start position: " + ui.item.startPos);
        console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }
});
```

Comment: You save my day! Sir question, how can I save the new position by using ajax?

Comment: Why don't they have a simple example like this on the sortable man pages?  I really didn't realize the items from `start` were capable of being in the `stop` scope until I saw this.

Comment: I don't get it why such a common functionality is not part of sortable...

Answer (score 14):

Use **update** instead of **stop**

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

> **update**( event, ui )
>
> Type: sortupdate
>
> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM
>   position has changed.

.

> **stop**( event, ui )
>
> Type: sortstop
>
> This event is triggered when sorting has stopped. event Type: Event

Piece of code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7a1836ce/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var sortable    = new Object();
sortable.s1     = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
sortable.s2     = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
sortable.s3     = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
sortable.s4     = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
sortable.s5     = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

sortingExample();

function sortingExample()
{
    // Init vars

    var tDiv    = $('<div></div>');
    var tSel    = '';

    // ul
    for (var tName in sortable)
    {

        // Creating ul list
        tDiv.append(createUl(sortable[tName], tName));
        // Add selector id
        tSel += '#' + tName + ',';

    }

    $('body').append('<div id="divArrayInfo"></div>');
    $('body').append(tDiv);

    // ul sortable params

    $(tSel).sortable({connectWith:tSel,
       start: function(event, ui) 
       {
            ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
       },
        update: function(event, ui)
        {
            var a   = ui.item.startPos;
            var b   = ui.item.index();
            var id = this.id;

            // If element moved to another Ul then 'update' will be called twice
            // 1st from sender list
            // 2nd from receiver list
            // Skip call from sender. Just check is element removed or not

            if($('#' + id + ' li').length < sortable[id].length)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(ui.sender === null)
            {
                sortArray(a, b, this.id, this.id);
            }
            else
            {
                sortArray(a, b, $(ui.sender).attr('id'), this.id);
            }

            printArrayInfo();

        }
    }).disableSelection();;

// Add styles

    $('<style>')
    .attr('type', 'text/css')
    .html(' body {background:black; color:white; padding:50px;} .sortableClass { clear:both; display: block; overflow: hidden; list-style-type: none; } .sortableClass li { border: 1px solid grey; float:left; clear:none; padding:20px; }')
    .appendTo('head');


    printArrayInfo();

}

function printArrayInfo()
{

    var tStr = '';

    for ( tName in sortable)
    {

        tStr += tName + ': ';

        for(var i=0; i < sortable[tName].length; i++)
        {

            // console.log(sortable[tName][i]);
            tStr += sortable[tName][i] + ', ';

        }

        tStr += '<br>';

    }

    $('#divArrayInfo').html(tStr);

}


function createUl(tArray, tId)
{

    var tUl = $('<ul>', {id:tId, class:'sortableClass'})

    for(var i=0; i < tArray.length; i++)
    {

        // Create Li element
        var tLi = $('<li>' + tArray[i] + '</li>');
        tUl.append(tLi);

    }

    return tUl;
}

function sortArray(a, b, idA, idB)
{
    var c;

    c = sortable[idA].splice(a, 1);
    sortable[idB].splice(b, 0, c);      

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the official documentation of the jquery sortable UI:
http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

In update event. use:

```
var sortedIDs = $( ".selector" ).sortable( "toArray" );
```

and if you alert or console this var (sortedIDs). You'll get your sequence.
**Please choose as the "Right Answer" if it is a right one.**