# Jquery UI sortable item position on change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In JqueryUI sortable, When the user drags a item, change event called. I got this on below example.

[jsFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleeswaran/dvSq2/2/)

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // When the item postion is changed while dragging a item, I want it's position
        console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }
```

In my code When the user drags a item (Item7) and changes the position , while dragging a item and changing the position . **I want to get the position of a dragging item.**

I just saw a answer here : [jQuery UI Sortable Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979643/jquery-ui-sortable-position)

In the above link, position value (**ui.item.index()**) is accessed on **Stop function**, while dragging a item, I want it's position (**on change function**) ? Any Idea ?

I need this because when the user tries to place a item7 after a item2, I will do some validation getting values from previous Item2 **(If I know the current position of the dragging item, Then only I can access previous item)** . If the validation is success, It can be placed or I have to show some message.

Comment: [This question & answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148145/drag-event-for-jquery-ui-sortable) seem to be of high use to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get the index of what's currently hovered, try using `placeholder`.

```
change: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("New position: " + ui.placeholder.index());
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JudeDuran/dvSq2/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Jude Duran's answer will not work constantly (found this out after taring my hair out). The first and last items placeholder move depending on the mouse location.

```
function getPaceholderIndex( ui ) {
    var clone = $(myMenu).clone();
    $('.ui-sortable-helper', clone).remove();
    return $('.ghost', clone).index();
}
```

will work more efficiently as it firstly removes the actual item and leaves the placeholder. Note that I have 'ghost' set as the placeholder parameter.