# HTML table with rowspan reorder item drag and drop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html code is

```
<table border='1px' id='sort'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>Sub Group</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='3'>1</td>
            <td rowspan='3'>Fruit</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>pineapple</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'>2</td>
            <td rowspan='2'>Flower</td>
            <td>Rose</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sunflower</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and js

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

I want to reorder only subgroup like fruit mango,orange or sunflower,rose not the main group in the table.
The working fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/p6c814o6/. How to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just make 1 table cell and then in that cell a sortable list?

Comment: That's a good idea. but when I add a new sub-group like `type of mango` then it will more difficult to show and the rowspan value actually come from database. That's why I want to keep this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

I have updated your fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6c814o6/2/). Your html was wrong according to your code. You must check your new html.
Instead Of using rowspans you must go with nested tables to achieve it.

```
<table border='1px' id='sort'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>Sub Group</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >1</td>
            <td >Fruit</td>
            <td><table>
                <tr>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>pineapple</td>
        </tr></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <tr>
            <td >2</td>
            <td >Flower</td>
            <td><table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                Rose
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>sunflower</td>
        </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Check out the updated fiddle. If this is what you need.
Hope this helps [JsFiddleUpdated](http://jsfiddle.net/p6c814o6/2/)

Comment: thanks but I want to reorder only the nested table not the main table. That was my requirement.

Comment: Thank you. One last issue, How to get nested table `index` with `td` so that i can update it in database via ajax request. I tried `$( "#sort tbody tr td > table tbody" ).sortable( "serialize", { key: 'td' } );` which does not work

Comment: Check this link. This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979643/jquery-ui-sortable-position.