# Store records in the same order as it displayed on screen. - Rails Sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-ui-sortable, cocoon-gem

I have a rails nested form, where we can sort form of `items`(Consider Item is a model). 
Consider i have filled form with 3 items later i sorted 3rd one to first position(am using jquery sortable to sort elements).

here each `item` model as postion field. I would like to set poistion to item based on it's order in form.

i know how to order element after creating. I can set element id to sortable div and calling sortable toArray gives me order of ids as visible.

```
$("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
```

using this i can easily set postions to record.
But in my current case i won't be having ids as we are creating records for first time. Please help me to implement this feature. Thanks.

Comment: Fill the position in in the record immediately using js, e.g. using something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979643/jquery-ui-sortable-position

Comment: Add ids using `.uniqueId()` https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/